# How to install kali linux gnome package offline

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

I installed kali linux in a virtual machine(windows 7). The install is completed but I'm getting the command line version. I want the GUI version. I did some research and I found out I need the gnome package. But the problem is that I don't have an internet connection in this PC. Is there anyway to install gnome package offline?

P.S : I knkw this is an duplicated question. But I didn't find any solutions to the questions asked before

Comment: Download the version with GUI instead?

Comment: I downloaded the official version from linux official page. I choosed the graphical install during the installation but it installed the command line mode. I don't know why

Comment: "Graphical Install" does not mean it installs a GUI - it means the setup uses a GUI

Comment: @panki any link to download the gui version please?

Comment: You are asked during installation which packages you would like to install.  When using the "Graphical Install", there should be a screen for "Software Selection".  Choose the desktop packages you would like to install.  If you are not using the NetInstaller, all the packages should come from the disk image.

Comment: @GracefulRestart The package gnome is not installed. I checked a "Desktop(I don't remember well but I remember it was desktop in the title)" box in the choose what to install window. I actually checked all of them.

Comment: this may help https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/5361#5361